# Particle-particle bubble

Tags: tikz-pgf, feynman, tikz-feynman

I want to draw a Feynman diagrams for the particle-particle bubble. I'm used to drawing Feynman-Diagrams with tikz-feynman in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman,contour}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex[blob,label={above:$P$}] (m) at ( 0, 0) {\contour{white}{$\leftarrow$}};
    \vertex (a) at (-2,-1) {$K' + P \\ \uparrow$};
    \vertex (b) at ( 2,-1) {$\uparrow \\ K + P$};
    \vertex (c) at (-2, 1) {$-K' \\ \downarrow$};
    \vertex (d) at ( 2, 1) {$\downarrow \\ -K$};
    \diagram* {
      (d) -- [fermion] (m) -- [fermion] (c),
      (b) -- [fermion] (m) -- [fermion] (a),
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this case I drew a 4-point vertex with a blob in the middle. But this time, I need a diagram that looks like this

[image]

but has a similar "style" as the one I made above (except for the big blob, that one won't be needed here). The main problem I had, was making the fermonic lines in the middle, that have a curve, which I'm not used to making.

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation for Ti*k*Z-Feynman?  You can find it on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman) and also on the [project's website](https://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman/).  In particular, there is an example of a self-energy diagram on page 25.

Comment: @JP-Ellis I edited my initial post.

Comment: I mention in the documentation how to add momentum arrows to any propagator.  Hint: use the `momentum=…` key :)

Comment: @JP-Ellis I tried that, but unfortunately, the momenta were squeezed on the inside of the bubble. It would be better, if they were on the outside. And I couldn't find a way to implement an arrow on the boson propagator.

Comment: Again, the documentation mentions how you can adjust which side the momentum arrows go on (hint, change between `momentum=…` and `momentum'=…`).  Also, have you had a look at the list of edge styles Ti*k*Z-Feynman offers?  You'll see that `charged boson` and `anti charged boson` are bosons with arrows.  Lastly, it is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question, and in fact, it is preferred to do that than to edit your answer into the original question because it is clearer for other readers.

Comment: @JP-Ellis I tried that, but my new problem is, that it gives me an additional "curly arrow" on top of the propagator. How can I avoid such a curly arrow and just give it my label for the momentum?

/Nvm, it worked with edge label. Thanks a lot!.

Comment: If you just want a label, without the momentum arrow, use the `edge label` style (and just like `momentum`, it also has a corresponding `edge label'` style too switch sides).

Comment: @JP-Ellis Thanks a lot, it works perfectly fine now!

Comment: If it works fine, please post your solution as an answer, and then accept that answer (also, you'll have to edit out the answer from your initial question).  This'll make it easier for others to find what the question was, and how it was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer with the help of JP-Ellis

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman,contour}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=c to b] { a -- [photon] b
-- [fermion, half right, looseness=1.5] c
-- [fermion, half right, looseness=1.5] b, c -- [photon] d,
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```